# How to start animation between routers after component's data is been load from a service

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

I have a nice animation between my routes and I added a warp to every component to show the component only after the data has been loaded, it's look like this:

my component HTML file:

```
<div *ngIf="isDataAvailable">
   ...my component html template...
</div>
```

and this is my ts file:

```
isDataAvailable:boolean = false;
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.clientsService.getClients().subscribe(
      (result:any) => {
        this.data = result.clients;
        this.isDataAvailable = true;
      }
    );
}
```

in my root ts file I have this animation settings:

```
import { customTransition } from './custom-transition.animation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-master',
  templateUrl: './master.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './master.component.css',
  ],
  animations: [customTransition()],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

and this is my HTML template for the root file

```
<ng2-page-transition [animation]="customAnimation">
    <div [@ng2ElementState]="customAnimation.state">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</ng2-page-transition>
```

my issue right now is that some components are loading fast and some are loading slowly because of the data they have and this is fine but those that are loading slowly the user don't see the animation but just the component is shown when it is ready.

I would like to start the animation after the data is beeing load
maybe even to show some preloader for the user before the component is ready.

thank you!

EDIT:

this is my customTransition.animation.ts file:

```
//custom-transition.animation.ts
import {trigger, state, animate, style, transition, AnimationEntryMetadata} from '@angular/core';

export function customTransition():AnimationEntryMetadata {
  return slideOutAndIn();
}

function slideOutAndIn():AnimationEntryMetadata {
  return trigger('ng2ElementState', [
    state('leave', style({
        position:'inherit', 
        display:'block',
        width:'100%'
    })),
    state('enter', style({
        position:'inherit', 
        display:'block',
        width:'100%'
    })),
    transition('* => enter', [
        style({
            transform: 'translateY(10%)',
            opacity: 0
        }),
        animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({
            transform: 'translateY(0%)',
            opacity: 1
        }))
    ]),
    transition('* => leave', [
      style({
        transform: 'translateY(0%)',
        opacity: 0
      }),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({
        transform: 'translateY(-10%)',
        opacity: 0
      }))
    ]),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: I think for your purpose the animation trigger should be contained in the inner component of router outlet. Anyways. You could manage to do a service that uses an observable what 'flags/gives info' when 'ngOnInit' of inner components to know when they are disposed and include it as trigger for the animation. Maybe an easier solution is proposed from masters. Let's see. Im interested.

Comment: @Sam I think you are right, maybe if I will trigger the animation inside the component it will work for me, I will add the animation in the question - could you please tell me how to run it inside my component? I'm a bit new in angular2...

Comment: I arrived home. am I late? all fine? If I can help let me know it :)

Answer (score 2):

the animation should be inside the component and not in the root file,
so this is my result:

```
import {trigger, state, animate, style, transition, AnimationEntryMetadata} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.css'],
  animations: [trigger('slideIn', [
    state('inactive', style({
        transform: 'translateY(10%)',
            opacity: 0
    })),
    state('active', style({
        transform: 'translateY(0%)',
            opacity: 1
    })),
    transition('active => inactive', animate('.6s ease')),
    transition('inactive => active', animate('.6s ease'))]
  ]
})

export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  state:string = "inactive";

  constructor( private clientsService: ClientsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateData();
  }

  updateData(){
    this.subscription = this.clientsService.getClients().subscribe(
      (result:any) => {
        this.data = result.clients;
        this.state = "active";
      }
    );
  }
}
```